# Return other column value from MAX of date

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3 and I'm trying to return 1 value (Amount) from a record based on the max value of another field (date) in the same record. My data looks something like this:

```
Type          Date          Amount       Cust
-----------------------------------------------------

Credit        2015-01-01    10           A
Inv           2015-01-01    11           A
Check         2015-01-01    12           A
Check         2015-01-02    13           A
Inv           2015-01-02    12           A
```

In actual fact, I need 2 fields - Last Check Date and Last Pay Amount. The Last Check Date I can get by using:

```
=Max(iif(Fields!type.Value = "CHECK", Fields!date.Value, Nothing))
```

My data is in date order so I had hoped something similar would work to get the Last Check amount, like:

```
=Last(iif(Fields!type.Value = "CHECK", Fields!amount.Value, Nothing))
```

but what I think this is doing is looking for the last record in the whole dataset and if it is type = check, then it gives me the amount, otherwise nothing. Unfortunalty, the last record is often not a check. This aproach results in nothing being displayed. I also tried wrapping the "last" inside the iif but this has the same effect.

In short, from the above dataset I would be looking to produce the following. I have one group in report builder - Cust and I have no detail section

```
Cust              A
Last Chk Date     2015-01-02
Last Chk Amt      13
```

I'm usually good at searching around for the answers to these type issue but for this one, I've drawn a complete blank! Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it is the best solution, but you can try to use the expression with Lookup or LookupSet function.

Lookup looks like a better option but it returns the first value but not the last. LookupSet returns all values and then with Right function you can "cut" the last value.

For last date: `=Right(Join(LookupSet("Check",Fields!Type.Value,Fields!Date.Value,"DataSet1"),","),InStrRev(Join(LookupSet("Check",Fields!Type.Value,Fields!Date.Value,"DataSet1"),","),",")-1)`

For last amount: `=Right(Join(LookupSet("Check",Fields!Type.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"DataSet1"),","),InStrRev(Join(LookupSet("Check",Fields!Type.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"DataSet1"),","),",")-1)`

[image]

Comment: I'd rather not have to use a separate tablix as there is other data above and below the section I'm stuck with that I need to display (sorry, should have explained that above).

Comment: I have just updated the answer with possible solution without adding the separate tablix in the report.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your efforts, I've marked your answer as accepted. Using the Lookupset was the key. As it turned out, using the exact code from your answer gave me a long concatenated list of almost all of either the Date or Amount field from every "check" record. I found that the RevInStr was looking for the *first* occurrence of the comma from the right side of the string. So the Right was displaying everything after that. To get it working for me, I used InStr(StrReverse to work out the number of characters I needed.

I'm not sure of the etiquette regarding comments vs answers but I couldn't get a comment to include my explanation and code. I thought I should post my changes in case this helps anyone else...

```
=Right(Join(LookupSet("Check", Fields!type.Value, Fields!date.Value, "credit"), ","), InStr(StrReverse(Join(LookupSet("Check", Fields!type.Value, Fields!date.Value, "credit"), ",")), ",") - 1)
```

Thanks again for the help Michael, it's much appreciated.